# How can I construct/modify conflict resolution to make player tactical skill a primary determining factor in combat?

Tags: combat, fate-2.0

While I find **FATE 2.0**'s conflict resolution system satisfying for many purposes, one area where it frequently falls short is in highly-detailed combat. If I'm expected series of highly detailed one-on-one duels between swordsmen of different styles and skill sets, how can I best set up the conflict resolution system to present meaningful choices to the players during play, such that formulating a sufficiently high-quality plan of action for one's turn or failing to do so significantly impacts the course and ultimately the outcome of combat encounters?  How can the dynamic skill system be leveraged to support this style of play, and what additional subsystems are useful for this?

Please support your answer with actual play or GMing experience using FATE 2.0 (or other appropriate FATE-2.0-specific support).  Answers based on a modern Fate perspective are exceedingly unlikely to be helpful here.